I'm getting the error "InvalidParameter" while trying to create nodes in my AKS Cluster
I'm trying to install CAST AI, a tool that helps to reduce kubernetes costs, the tool is trying to create a agentPools in my cluster but i'm getting the following error:
{ "code": "InvalidParameter", "details": null, "message": "All or none of the agentpools should set podsubnet", "subcode": "" }

Does anyone knows how can i solve this issue?
I've tried to reproduce the error in other AKS cluster and searching for issues with this error but can't find nothing.

What's the network config? This message seems to be indicating problems with how you have or have not set up the subnetting.
